# Each time downloading javascript bundle ios device

Tags: react-native

I am using iphone 6s for development. When debug mode is on device downloading javascript bundle when i did change javascript code and it takes 15-20sec. When debug is off its just refresing and everything works fine.

[image]

does anybody knows whats the issue?

Answer (score 0):

When the debug mode is on it definitely takes more time since it has to rebuild your entire JS, while when it's off it needs to just re-render where the change is made so it refreshes in a moment. It's not an issue necessarily, you are forcing it to rebuild and check for any possible error when you turn the debug mode on!

Comment: Thank you for your response. Its not happened on simulator debug mode, it just refreshing not downloading. So what makes it difference?

Comment: I didn't get what you're concerned with?